# VBS, when opening an Excel file, changes number format, destroying data

Tags: excel, vbscript

when try to open an excel file using VBScript, the values/numbers format gets change, destryoing the values.

For example: "0.0" is changed to "__0.0" (with spaces befores), "9000.0" is turned into "__9000.0" (with spaces befores) and "288" is replaced by "288000".

Some knows how to solve this?

Here is my code to open the file:

```
    Dim ExcelFile 

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True

    Set ExcelFile = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("File Directory")
```

I need the data as original (functional) in order to be used by another file.

Comment: And what happens to those data if you manually ask Excel to open the file? Also what is the file format of the file to be opened? CSVs and other text files are often mangled by Excel.

Comment: Hi, if I manually open the file, it doesn´t brake the data.... almost all data is in text format, but some of it is in number format... I don´t know why.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the file, or a suitably similar one?

Comment: I tried running your code to open a .xlsx and a .csv both seemed to work just fine, though as ever with the .csv some formatting was lost, but certainly not mangled the way you suggest. Assuming it's a csv or other kind of text file, how does it look if you open in notepad (or your text editor or choice).

Comment: Finding a solution will be difficult until you give enough detail to at least allow us to replicate the problem.